# Creating new serial device ttyS4 in /dev/

Tags: linux

Can anyone help me in adding two more devices ttyS4 and ttyS5 in /dev directory.?

As an embedded developer, I need to access two more serial ports available on my development board. I tried to create two more new device like ttyS1 - ttyS3, but I am failing in every step. I used `setserial /dev/ttyS4 port FB000000 irq 7 autoconfig`, but result is useless to me. Is it required to write for a module? Is there any way to access same ttyS1 - ttyS3 code for newly creating serial device `ttyS4` and `ttyS5`?

Comment: "result is useless to me" - what *is* the result and how does it differ from the expected?

Answer (score 0):

Serial ports aren't autodetected... at a minimum you need to go into the kernel and modify your board definition file to take into account the extra two serial ports. And recompile.

If you want more specific help you need to specify your embedded linux build system and what board you're based on.